# FL Studio: How can I change the instruments of an imported MIDI file?

Tags: midi, fl-studio

[image]

I have imported a MIDI file into Fruity Loops. It sounds fine so far, but now I want to change the instruments before I export it to ogg.

But whenever I change an instrument, FL is changing it back to the default when I press the stop button when I change it during play or when I press play when I changed it while the song was stopped.
How can I change the instrument for my recording?

Answer (score 6):

How to change the midi command to change patches on the fly:

- Open the pattern in the piano roll.
- Choose "Target Control" from the piano roll options menu.
- Choose the one that says "Instrument in question - Patch number".
- Use the delete tool to select the event[s] and delete it.

You can also access patch number and other controls from the drop-down menu on the top of the piano roll window. By default it will have "velocity" chosen.

Answer (score 5):

1. You can drag another instrument from the hierarchy right on to the track
2. You can right-click on the track eg. [Channel #1], and there is an option to replace the channel
3. You can create a new channel with the synth you want and copy the piano-roll

--- unless you are just wanting to change it to a new instrument in the midi-player... in that case, examine the piano roll to make sure you don't have a change patch command at the start of the track. If you do, you'll need to remove it.

Comment: How would I recognize that change patch command? I examined all piano rolls and I only see notes there. Btw, it get's changed the moment I press the "stop" button when it plays and when I start it when I changed it while the song was not played.

Comment: I can't remember off hand how to do it in FL. Try drag-selecting and copying the piano roll to a new midi-out channel and mute that channel (by clicking the little green circle to the left of the channel). I wouldn't use CNTRL-A to select all though, you might still pick up that message.

Answer (score 0):

Putting this here for my own use.

Sometimes when the instrument doesn't want to be replaced, right click context menu > replace > (none).

Then drag an instrument over it like you normally would.